# Can I make Chrome more descriptive of errors?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jasmine

I'm new to BDD with Jasmine. In fact, I've just downloaded Jasmine, written my first spec, and launched the `SpecRunner.html` file. I have yet to write a particular `init` method, and in Firefox/Safari I see a nice description of this error:

```
(Firefox) TypeError: Object.create(...).init is not a function in file...
(Safari) TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.create(Seminar).init(seminarName)') in file...
```

However, in Chrome I see a technically correct, but disappointingly obtuse error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Seminar.create (file...Seminar.js:7:39)
```

Is there a way to make Chrome tell me the *actual* name of the missing method, as opposed to just the line number and column name of where the error occurred?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make Chrome tell me the actual name of the missing method, as opposed to just the line number and column name of where the error occurred?

No, but looking at the line and column should tell you what it is. You can also use Chrome's Dev Tools to make it stop execution on an exception that isn't handled, which will take you right to the place where the exception occurs, when it occurs, so you can inspect things. To do that:

1. Open Dev Tools
2. Go to the Sources pane
3. Click this icon on the right-hand side to turn it blue:

   [image]

When that icon is blue, it will make Chrome stop when an exception occurs that isn't caught (there's also a checkbox that will appear if you want to stop on exceptions that *are* caught).